# SKStoreProductViewController buttons displaying in White color

Tags: ios, storekit

I am using SKStoreProductViewController in my app.Some times buttons are showing in white colour. how to change button colour to default colour.

Answer (score 0):

Since SKStoreProductViewController is an OS view controller, it should have consistent presentation every time you open it (that's the case from my experience), unless if maybe you are open it from different OS versions.
Please describe what do you mean in "sometimes" - what are you doing different?